# MySQL ExtractValue with variable

Tags: mysql

I have a XML like

```
 <info>
   <name>John</name>
   <sname>Doe</sname>
 </info>
```

Table with variables like object_name := "name", object_surname = "sname" 
And MySQL query like

```
SELECT @name = CONCAT('/info/', object_name) FROM table
```

Which give me a variable. @name = '/info/name', it`s OK.
Then I do a query:

```
SELECT ExtractValue(:info, '/info/name') AS name FROM table2
```

It works fine, but if I change it to

```
SELECT ExtractValue(:info, @name) AS name FROM table2
```

It shows nothing.
Do you have some solutions?

Comment: Did you tried `@name:`?

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstand the question. I hope that you could able to find the correct answer.

Comment: do you set that variable in the **same session** that you also `SELECT`?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT @name = CONCAT('/info/', object_name) FROM table
```

compares $name to CONCAT....

[= is the assignement operator only for SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-equal),for SELECT use :=

in your case use

```
SELECT @name := CONCAT('/info/', object_name) FROM table
```